# Python: How to convert float to string without `.0`?

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to extract telephone number from `*.xls` with module `xlrd` using Python, but it shows like this:`'16753435903.0'`.

Here's the code:

```
opensheet = openxls.sheet_by_name(u'sms')
sheetrows = opensheet.nrows
for rownum in range(1, sheetrows):
    rowvalue = opensheet.row(rownum)
    execinfo = ""
    for colnum in range(1,5):
        execinfo += "'"+str(rowvalue[colnum].value)+"',"
```

The key part:

> str(rowvalue[colnum].value)

How can I get the well format telephone number without `.0`?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a very simple workaround: convert the number to an `int` before converting it to a string?